# Why does `word (.(?!another-word))*?` match only a character?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string

```
my $text = 
  "abc " .
  "VVV foo III " .                # <- here
  "pqr hash def " .
  "VVV bar hash baz III " .       # <- here
  "stu hash ghi " .
  "VVV bbb, ccc hash ddd III " .  # <- here
  "vwx";
```

In this text, I want to replace the word `hash` if it occurs between the words `VVV` and `III`. Potential fragments for substitution are marked with `<- here` in the snippet above. The first fragment does not have the word `hash`, so no substitution can take place there.

I have come up with the following regular expression:

```
$text =~ s/ VVV (.(?!III))*? hash (.*?)(?=III)/ VVV $1 HASH $2/g;
```

With this regex, `$text` becomes

```
abc VVV foo III pqr hash def VVV r HASH baz III stu hash ghi VVV c HASH ddd III vwx
```

The replacements are made at the right places, *however*, the text preceeding `hash` is replaced with one character only (`VVV r HASH` instead of `VVV bar HASH` and `VVV c HASH` instead of `VVV bbb, ccc HASH`).

I don't understand why this happens. As far as I understand regular expressions, the `VVV` should act as an anchor and thus make sure that every character after it is matched.

Comment: I think you need to use `VVV ((?:(?!III).)*?) hash (.*?)(?=III)` pattern. Or even `VVV ((?:(?!VVV|III).)*?) hash (.*?)(?=III)`

Comment: Your proposed pattern seems to work, indeed.

Comment: This looks a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) in your pattern. To write it correctly, you need to put the lookahead *before* the dot you want to "temper", use a non-capturing group to wrap the lookahead with the dot, and *capture* the whole substring matched with the construct within another capturing group.

```
/VVV ((?:(?!III).)*?) hash (.*?III)/
     ^              ^
```

Note there is no point putting `III` into a positive lookahead, you may as well match and capture it to be restored later with `$2`.

Now, the `((?:(?!III).)*?)` will capture into Group 1 any char (other than line breaks), 0 or more occurrences, as few as possible, that does not start a `III` character sequence.

Comment: Ok, I now understand why I have to put the `(?!III)` in front of the `.`. But I still don't get which part of my (wrong) regexp "eats" or "covers" the `ba` of `bar` and `bbb, cc` of `bbb, ccc`.

Comment: When you do not wrap the whole tempered greedy token within a capturing group, the `(.(?!III))*?` subpattern matches any char that is not followed with `III` substring and *captures* this char into Group 1. Since the quantifier `*?` is set to the whole *grouping construct*  `(.(?!III))`, the capture group value is *re-written* each time the char is matched and captured. It is called a *repeated capturing group*. Read [*Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html),  it should be clear to you then.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. It was very helpful. I was, in fact, unaware of the difference between "Repeating a Capturing Group" and "Capturing a Repeated Group".

Answer (score 2):

Because: `(.(?!III))*?` - the star is outside the brackets, rather than inside, so you're not capturing all the occurrences - just one. (The last one).

As [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) notes in the comments:

```
/VVV ((?:(?!III).)*?) hash (.*?)(?=III)/
```

Does what you want.

But I'd suggest that you're just trying to get far too complicated with your regex, and that really what you *should* be doing is breaking down the problem a bit further - multi-matching if necessary to get inclusion;exclusion sets.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "abc " . 
  "VVV foo III " .                  # <- here
  "pqr hash def " . 
  "VVV bar hash baz III " .         # <- here
  "stu hash ghi " . 
  "VVV bbb, ccc hash ddd III " .    # <- here
  "vwx";

#split your block on VVV, without removal
for ( split /(?=VVV)/, $text ) {
   #replace 'this chunk' so between 'VVV' and 'III' 
   s/hash (.*) III/HASH $1 III/g;
   #print the line. Or you could insert this back into your primary text
   print;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by splitting the string on whitespace and iterating through the resulting list, using the *range operator* to determine whether any given occurrence of `hash` is eligible for alteration

It would look like this. Note that the `split` also captures the intervening white space so that tabs or multiple spaces can be replaced as they were

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $text =
    "abc " .
    "VVV foo III " .                  # <- here
    "pqr hash def " .
    "VVV bar hash baz III " .         # <- here
    "stu hash ghi " .
    "VVV bbb, ccc hash ddd III " .    # <- here
    "vwx"
;

my @text = split /(\s+)/, $text;

for ( @text ) {
    my $in_range = $_ eq 'VVV' .. $_ eq 'III';
    $_ = 'HASH' if $_ eq 'hash' and $in_range;
}

say join '', @text;
```

#### output

```
abc VVV foo III pqr hash def VVV bar HASH baz III stu hash ghi VVV bbb, ccc HASH ddd III vwx
```